# Switching crystals circuit

Tags: signal, clock, crystal, resonator

This is for NES clock circuit. I need to find a way to switch the crystal between PAL and NTSC. I have used a normal switch to switch those with no problem. Same goes obviously with a relay, but I'm trying to think how to switch it with some transistor or something else.

This is a working video switch. Very elegant. I tried same approach with crystals, but doesn't work:

[image: video switch]

So any idea what to use to switch crystals on this circuit? I can double the whole circuit and switch that, it works, but too many parts when I could swap only the crystal itself.

[image: clock generator]

I have tried already 4066 but it doesn't work. I was thinking about optoisolators but their frequency is not enough. Maybe transistor didn't work because it's inverting, but how to do non-inverting properly? I tried something like this(only one crystal to test):

[image: non-working non-inverting abomination]

I have already ordered some small relays (G6K-2F-Y) just in case I cannot come up with anything. They are surely to work.

---

Does this look like it could work? Based on what @GodJihyo said. Compare to the original post. Those wires going off-picture would be the enabling voltages.

[image]

Comment: When trying to use a transistor as a switch, consider what happens to the base current flowing through that transistor and how it affects the rest of the circuit. You can't just pretend that a transistor can switch things like a relay can.

Comment: Yea i know it's not just a switch. It's basically an amplifier that can be used as a switch. I can do only very basic transistor/fet circuits. I'm thinking that the crystal signal passing though would be the same, just a little amplified in the process.

Comment: Could try a double-pole single-throw relay, but note three things: 1. Some relays have a "wetting current" minimum (such as 5mA) and will not work reliably with the tiny currents of a crystal.  2. The extra wiring (clock signal through the relay contacts) will introduce parasitic capacitance and inductance which might affect operation.  And 3. This long length of clock trace (now going through a relay) might make an excellent antenna if it's length is close to the wavelength (MHz) being used.

Comment: Didn't think of that... My experiments with some heavy many-amp relays were working mostly but crashing occasionally. I though i was because i had like 15cm unshielded wires going to the NES board and they are rated for 230V switching. Of course that, but also what you said.

Comment: Just use 2 ILS switches and a magnet ...

Comment: What is an ILS switch? Couldn't find any proper info about that. Like a reed switch? Quite far fetched of running this with magnet(a coil)... Or is it? Basically a relay...

Comment: Yes "reed switch" ... but only the "internal" part , the small glass tube ... https://www.littelfuse.com/products/magnetic-sensors-and-reed-switches.aspx  or Reed relays

Comment: Can you tell more about your idea? You just come and say to use a reed with a magnet.

Comment: Reed relays are small (DIP form) ... one can fix one above the other for  ... and power to switch not too great. As @rdtsc suggested.

Comment: Something as this https://docs.rs-online.com/4867/A700000007106472.pdf

Comment: Hmm... reading more seems that reed relays would be better for this task than signal relays, because they have no "wetting current". And further reading, the G6K relays are sealed with no wetting current.

Thank you.

Comment: @Quezacotl The diode switching circuit you posted won't work. The diodes to the right are DC blocked by the capacitors and the ones at the bottom will switch the crystals so they're from the collector to ground, so you'd get no oscillation. I'll try to take a look at the problem tonight and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 1):

One method of switching crystals involves using diodes. A diode is put in series with each crystal and a voltage is used to bias the diodes on or off. RF chokes are used to keep the bias voltage from loading down the signal from the crystals.
This was done in things like police scanners and CB radios quite a bit, so you might look for schematics of those for some ideas on how to implement it.

Comment: Like this?
https://www.radiomods.co.nz/xtalswitch.html
Then to figure out how to implement it :/

Comment: @Quezacotl Yes, that's the basic idea. Of course it's going to be easier with some oscillator configurations than others. Optimally the oscillator would be a type where one side of the crystal is grounded, but it's possible with other types. In radio circuits diode switching is also used for selecting different filters and for transmit/receive switching.

Comment: Yes, it's best to use a common-collector or common-base oscillator if you're going to use diode switching.  The buffer stage will have to change, and you'll need to have individual trim capacitors for each crystal.